# IIS Workers CPU usage on Windows Server 2016

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-express, windows-server-2016

I have been trying to increase max allowed CPU usage by IIS Application on my Windows Server.

Here's the thing : 
When I launch my webapi on Visual Studio IIS the request is proceed within 1,7 sec.

When I launch webapi on my PC's IIS the request is proceed within 3,5 sec.

And finally when I launch webapi on my other machine which has WS 2016 the request is proceed within 10 secs.

CPU usage on VS IIS - can reach 90%.
CPU usage on my PC IIS - can reach 35%.
CPU usage on WS 2016 IIS - can reach max 10%.

My question is, how can I increase max cpu usage on IIS process workers? I have been trying everything :

- changing limits in Application Pool settings
- changed process priority in Task Manager to "Real Time" and cpu usage increased from 3% to 10% but still it's not enough.

Comment: Do all the machines have the same number of CPU cores? The CPU value shown in Task Manager is normalized to the total number of CPUs, i.e., to have a process show 100% utilization on a 16 core machine you need to fully utilize 16 cores at once.

Comment: No, the server machine has 8 cores and my PC has only 4.